# Please welcome your newest pro tem moderators

Tags: discussion

I'm Pops, a Community Manager at Stack Exchange. I'm here today to announce that you're getting not just one, but **two** great new pro tem moderators:

[image: Wrzlprmft]
[image: Loong]
<sub>(source: [stackexchange.com](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/flair/9551.png))</sub>

Wrzlprmft and Loong are joining your long-time moderator Takkat to help take care of things behind the scenes. So without further ado, please join me in welcoming your new mods, as well as thanking the retiring splattne and RegDwight for their service!

Comment: What is a tem moderator and a pro tem moderator? Do you mean team? I only find tem: http://dict.leo.org/ende/?search=tem in this way, but since it occurs twice it doesn't seem to be a typo.

Comment: It's short for "pro tempore." Maybe only Americans usually abbreviate in this way? But it means something like "for the time being."

Comment: @userunknown, I did not know the term either, but as we tell German learners, you just have to use the right dictionary :) http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/pro-tem?q=tem

Comment: In German: *auf Zeit*

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is great news and a good choice.

I am sure German Language will get a very good moderation with two very much appreciated users. I look forward to working together with Wrzlprmft and Loong on keeping German Language a good place for us all. Of course I am happy to get some help for all that janitorial work too.

However this is not without tears for our now retired moderators Splattne and RegDwight who did such a wonderful job in building up this site. We will miss your advice and your always fair and unbiased judging. Let's hope you continue to contribute.